# Programmatically check if a user has certain permissions for an S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-cli, aws-java-sdk

I would like to check if a given user / role can perform a certain operation (GetObject, PutObject etc) on an S3 bucket. I can do this manually though the AWS console by examining the user's policies, but I was curious if there was a way to do this via the CLI or the Java SDK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simulate how a set of IAM policies attached to an IAM entity works with a list of API operations and AWS resources to determine the policies' effective permissions.

Two APIs are available:

1. [SimulatePrincipalPolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_SimulatePrincipalPolicy.html)
2. [SimulateCustomPolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_SimulateCustomPolicy.html)

Also see the re:Invent 2016 slide deck on [How to Automate Policy Validation](https://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/aws-reinvent-2016-how-to-automate-policy-validation-sec311).

Comment: Link to the video which is very good: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pm-4vSMSDyc